# Heat equation with jump initial condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the heat equation

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}{u_t}\left( {x,t} \right) - \Delta u\left( {x,t} \right) = 0{\rm{   for }}x \in R,{\rm{ }}t > 0\\u\left( {x,0} \right) = \phi \left( x \right){\rm{   for }}x \in R.\end{array} \right.$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the jump function given by $\phi \left( x \right) = 1$ if $x\ge 0$, $\phi \left( x \right) = 0$ if $x\lt 0 .$

(a) Show that the solution satisfies
$$\underset{t\to {{0}^{+}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1+0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\text{ }.$$
(b) Does the 2-dimensional limit 
$\text{ }\underset{(x,t)\to (0,{{0}^{+}})}{\mathop{\lim }}\,u\left( x,t \right)$ exist or not? Why?

I tried to solve (a) as follows but without much confidence.  Please help.  No idea for (b) either.

$\begin{align}
  & u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\frac{{{\left( x-y \right)}^{2}}}{4t}}}\phi \left( y \right)dy} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{-\frac{{{y}^{2}}}{4t}}}\phi \left( x-y \right)dy} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\phi \left( x-z\sqrt{4t} \right)\sqrt{4t}dz} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\phi \left( x-z\sqrt{4t} \right)dz}  
\end{align}$

Then
$\begin{align}
  & \underset{t\to {{0}^{+}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{0}{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\underset{t\to {{0}^{+}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\phi \left( x-z\sqrt{4t} \right)dz}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\underset{t\to {{0}^{+}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\phi \left( x-z\sqrt{4t} \right)dz} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{0}{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\cdot 0dz}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-{{z}^{2}}}}\cdot 1dz} \\ 
 & =0+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{2}  
\end{align}$